# Admin rights 2 apps

Tags: c++, windows

We have an app1 with requireAdministrator in manifest and this app is launching app2.
App2 manifest file contains as asInvoker.
Will app2 inherit admin rights?

Answer (score 0):

Usually I think the answer is 'yes'.

Note however that there are two different concepts, one is the user privileges and one is the integrity level of a running process.

A standard user can launch 'low' and 'medium' integrity leveled processes, while a administrator also can launch 'high' leveled processes. The default for all users usually is 'medium'.

ProcessExplorer can be very helpful to see a processes' integrity level (just add the column).